# Django URL reversing NoReverseMatch issue

Tags: regex, django, django-views, django-urls

I'm trying to use reverse to redirect a user to a login page from a third party App I'm using.
The URL config has:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # authentication / association
    url(r'^login/(?P<backend>[^/]+){0}$'.format(extra), views.auth,
        name='begin'),
```

How can I accomplish this? I've tried

```
return redirect(reverse('social:login'), args=('facebook',))
```

and

```
return redirect(reverse('social:login'), kwargs={'backend':fb})
```

(to get to /login/facebook) but I'm getting a NoReverseMatch

The Django URL system and RegExes are confusing me a bit =(

**EDIT**: All right, it looks like I was making a mess with these URLs.
A simple solution that works (thank you @Alasdair in the comments):

```
return redirect('social:begin', backend='facebook')
```

Comment: It's not my App, it's django-social-auth (https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth)

Comment: `redirect(reverse('begin', kwargs={'backend': 'fb'}))` will get your browser to views.auth

Comment: You don't need to use `reverse` with redirect, so you can take @mbieren's answer and simplify it to `redirect('begin', backend='fb')`.

Comment: I've found a solution and posted it as an edit to my question, I hope it's the appropriate way to signal it to people. Thanks!